# Execute code on input change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 4 textboxes and a label at the end of the textboxes. I would like to change the label to `complete` once the input's value has been changed.  I do not want to use a button to fire this event and instead would like to monitor when the field loses focus, such as through tabbing to the next input or clicking out of the current input.  Tricky part is that there is a default value (ghost text) in each text box, which will have to be checked before marking the corresponding input as `complete`. So I am going to have to check whether the css color of the text is set to the "ghost text" color before the validation is complete.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by "ghost text"?

Comment: have you considered using the validation plugin? http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for what i needed, thanks guys

function ontextChange() {
        $('input:text,textarea').keyup(function () {
            $('input:text,textarea').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    $('[id$=lblUploadStatus]').html('Ready to upload.');
                }
                else {
                    $('[id$=lblUploadStatus]').html('Incomplete').css({ 'color': 'red' });
                }
            });
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Add an onblur handler, loop over all the related fields and check if they're filled in. if they are, then display your message.

```
$('.textfields').blur(function() {
   cnt = 0;
   $('.textfields').each(function() {
      if ((this.value != 'blur text') && (this.value != '')) {
         cnt++;
      }
   });
   if (cnt == $('.textfields').length) {
      $('.label').html('All done!');
   }
});
```

not tested, probably won't work, YMMV, etc...

Comment: I think using `.change()` would be preferable to `.blur()` where textfields are concerned.

Comment: maybe, but then this'd fire for every character entered.

Comment: Why would that be a problem here?

Comment: I tend to NOT have field validation fire until after the user is obviously done with the field. I absolutely LOATHE systems that go "You haven't entered enough text yet, nya nya nyah", right after the first character.

Comment: My concern was that `.blur()` won't fire until he focuses out of the last textfield. More often than not, I myself will submit a form by hitting "enter" after I type text into the last form field, so your approach wouldn't ever notify me that I had completed the form.

Comment: Easy enough: put a validate call on the submit button to double check.

Comment: ...which won't work either, if I never clicked the submit button. :-)

Comment: fine, an `onsubmit` on the form itself. Regardless, javascript verification of a form is utterly pointless, and if the op wants bulletproof verification, it'll HAVE to be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The code below by Marc B won't work if they don't blur out of the last field. Unfortunately, there's not a good way to find out if the user is done typing in the last field unless they tab or click out of the text box. Other solutions that come to mind are onkeyup of the last text field check to see if it's equal to the buffer text that was present before, if not, then we know they have changed the text, again this seems like a really bad way to assume they are done. The simplest way is to include a submit button.